# Configure font weight for FiraFlott in VS Code

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

Integrated FiraFlott font in VS Code.
The default font weight seems too bold other wise nice font. Changing the font weight in VS Code has no effect for this particular font. Is this font available in multiple font weights versions or is there any way to adjust the font weight for this font in VS Code?

VS Code version: 1.29.1
OS: Windows 10

Comment: so you had tried adding "editor.fontWeight": "normal" in your user settings(and reloaded vscode), but still the font has no change in weight?

Comment: Actually, by default "editor.fontWeight" propertry is set to normal only for which the font appears somewhat bold. I tried other font-weigth values like 100, 200, etc., but the font-weight did not changed. This is happening for this particular font only. For other fonts, font-weight is getting applied correctly when changed

Comment: Then it's the problem with the font. Like not all fonts have a ttf variant for Regular, Bold, Italic and so on. Currently i think only the bold variant of your font is installed in your system. Maybe installing the "Regular" or "Complete" type of this particular font in your system would enable normal font for you.

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari did you find the answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

- First see if you have installed fonts of different weights (as said by @**Yedhin** in the comments).
- For me ,I had installed *Fira Code* , but VS Code always chose the bold one, even if I try to change font weight.
  Then deleting the bold type of the font and keeping other types(including semi bold type) solved my problem, I could now change the font weight in the VS code settings

VS Code version : 1.35.1 ,OS : Windows 10

Comment: Thanks for this tip: I had a similar problem where I wanted to reduce the weight of *Fira Code*'s bold -- disabling the bold font caused it to fall back on SemiBold, which is much better (macOS: open "Font Book", find *Fira Code*, click triangle to expand, R-click Bold, choose *disable*).